# EPPlus number format is changed in Excel

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPlus to write to Excel file. I need to format my number in German culture which uses dot (.) as a thousand separator and comma (,) as a decimal separator.

When I set the formatting, it changed in Excel. Here is my code:

```
//without decimal 
worksheet.Cells[2, 5].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#.##0";
```

But in Excel, it becomes

```
Cells[2, 5] ---> #,##0
```

Any idea?

Comment: Putting Epplus aside for a moment, can this even be done in excel without changing the region settings for the OS or Excel itself?  With date/time it can be done but how would it be done for a number for just a single cell?

Comment: Well, you are spot on! You need to change the region or go to options and un-tick *Use system separators*. The problem was the excel file is open using Excel with Deutsch (ie. German - which uses dot as thousand separators) and it doesn't work. Somehow EPPlus changed the formating to #,##0.